# splitting a string doesn't work for me in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

My string is **"&&";"XMLWrirter";"class";"&&"** 
I want to spilt this string based on ; delimiter.
And when I do like below , I am getting first word only printed and count as 1.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set argC=0
for /f "delims=;" %%x in (""&&";"XMLWrirter";"class";"&&"") do (Set /A argC+=1  
echo tokenitem %%x)
echo tokencount !argC!
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: When I try to run this I get a syntax error ...

Comment: Please remember that /f works on lines and what you provide is a single line with multiple values

Comment: You'll need to escape `&` with `^`; to split the string you'll need to specify `"tokens=1-4 delims=;"`, change the `for` variable to `%%a` and extract variables `%%a`, `%%b`, `%%c`, `%%d` to get all tokens;

Comment: @aschipfl No need to escape if you don't use `/F`! Check my code below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so complicated? This works just fine:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET argC=0
FOR %%x IN ("&&";"XMLWrirter";"class";"&&") DO (
    SET /A argC+=1
    ECHO tokenitem %%x
)
ECHO tokencount !argC!
```

Comment: Great!! I am new to batch programming and this simply worked for me. Thank you!!